# Why does it skip the "control" segment?

Tags: java

so I'm trying to ask the user to input value for control right after the SOP is done.  But it skips it for some reason.

```
public static void main(String [] args)
      {
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

         System.out.println("What's your balance?");
         double initialBalance = keyboard.nextDouble();

         Account chase = new Account(initialBalance);

         System.out.println(chase + "; Would you like to deposit or withdraw?");
         String control = keyboard.nextLine();

         if(control == "deposit")
         {
            double deposit = keyboard.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("How much would you like to deposit? " +
                                 deposit);
            chase.deposit(deposit);
            System.out.println(chase);                     

         }

      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snippet of your code with the changes required.

```
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("What's your balance?");
        double initialBalance = keyboard.nextDouble();
        keyboard.nextLine();

        Account chase = new Account(initialBalance);

        System.out.println("; Would you like to deposit or withdraw?");
        String control = keyboard.nextLine();

        if (control .equals("deposit") ){

        System.out.println("How much would you like to deposit? " );
        double deposit = keyboard.nextDouble();
        keyboard.nextLine();
```

The comments are clear. You would need to see the two post that they pointed to. Briefly there is a line separator that comes in and the importance of the equals method and its significance.

Answer (score 0):

> New Code:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("What's your balance?");
   double initialBalance = keyboard.nextDouble();

   Account chase = new Account(initialBalance);

   System.out.println(chase + "; Would you like to deposit or withdraw?");

   String control2 = "deposit";
   boolean control = keyboard.next().equalsIgnoreCase(control2);

   if(control == true)
   {
      double deposit = keyboard.nextDouble();
      System.out.println("How much would you like to deposit? " +
                           deposit);
      chase.deposit(deposit);
      System.out.println(chase);                     

   }
```

}
}

Comment: Would you believe me if I say, that there is still a problem in this code?

Comment: yeah i changed the code for my eclipse : )

Comment: take the new code : ) , when you still have a Problem then i need the other class Account. Then i can test it in Eclipse

Comment: The problem is still there ;). How about testing your answer? You don't need that class, just remove all lines that mention this class or the variable `chase`. They are not necessary to find the problem. And btw, I'm not OP.

Comment: What's your balance?
1111
; Would you like to deposit or withdraw?
11111
Im hanging at the if(control == "deposit")

Comment: Wait whats the difference between doing .nextLine() and just .next()

Comment: And the new code works fine for me. Im using jGRASP

Comment: @PTheCoolGuy Please read both links that are posted under your question. They describe the difference and how you can compare strings. Both things are necessary to fix your code.

Comment: Ah, you use control == "deposit", but control is only the reference

Comment: I add new code for you

Comment: guys im a beginner and read the link but i still dont get the difference between nextLine() and next()

Comment: @Cronical You can remove the old code if this doesn't work. And `if(control.equalsIgnoreCase(control))` is not correct, too. This test will always be true.

Comment: Oh yes youre right xD

Comment: Now it should be correct, its 3 am here so im little tired^^